# Is the region $\mathbb{C} \setminus \gamma $ simply connected, where $\gamma (t) = t + it^2$.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness

> Let $ \gamma (t) = t + it^2$ be a curve in the complex plane, $0 \leq t \leq \infty$.
>
> Is $ D = \mathbb{C} \setminus \gamma $ simply connected?

The curve separates the complex plane in two parts, one above the curve and one below. What I find difficult is the point at $t = \infty$. Does this make the curve closed? And how can one make an argument about that $D$ is simply connected (if it is)?

Thanks.

Comment: $\,\infty\,$ is not a point unless you're talking of the extended complex plane, which you didn't mention.

Comment: the range of $t$ can't include $t=\infty$ since $\infty $ is not a complex number.

Comment: The question given on a previous exam in was: Does there exist a conformal mapping from $D$ to the unit disc. And by Riemann's mapping theorem there is one if $D$ is simply connected. I'm not sure how to respond to the issue you are pointing out, since this is the definition of $D$ given on that exam. Could it be a typo in the exam?

Comment: Compare your $D$ with one of [these domains](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimplyConnected.html).

Comment: It is not so easy to compare since my $D$ is unbounded

Comment: Is $D$ path connected?

Comment: When you say "above" and "below" the curve, it seems like you're thinking of $-\infty<t<\infty$.

Comment: @Ted Shirin, thanks for pointing that out. I made a mistake by drawing the graph of the curve for $ - \infty < t < \infty$, so it is not strange that the set appear disconnected to me :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In complex analysis, we *define* a nonempty proper subset $D\subset \mathbb C\cup \{\infty\}$ as simply connected if both $D$ and $(\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\})\setminus D$ are connected.

In your case, the complement is $\gamma([0,\infty])$, which is connected because it is the continuous image of a connected space. And it is easy to see that $D$ itself is path-connected: you can find a path consisting of a horizontal and a vertical line segement from any point $x+iy$ to $-1-i\in D$, either via $x-i$ or via $-1+iy$.